# Select in a form field's control source property

Tags: forms, ms-access, controls

I'm quite fresh at Access, and I'm trying to make a simple form work. My form presents a combobox that correctly shows all names from a table called `Courses`. Another textbox (called `Fee`) in the same form is supposed to lookup a value into the same table based on the value selected in the combobox. To do that, I have used the following SQL statement in the `Fee`'s Control Source property:

```
=(SELECT Fee FROM Courses WHERE Courses.Course=Forms.Register.Course;)
```

In the form, I always get a `#Name?` error. However, the same instruction works well if I run it as a normal query. Please also note that the form shows other fields as well from other tables. the form's Record Source is the following:

```
SELECT Register.*, Courses.Fee FROM Courses INNER JOIN Register ON Courses.Course = Register.Course;
```

I guess this should be a straightforward task, but so far I haven't been able to find a solution (if possible without using VBA). Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a SELECT statement as control source for a calculated control, but [Domain functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DLookup-Function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) are used for this:

```
=DLookup("Fee", "Courses", "Course = Forms!Register!Course")
```

But you can also add `Fee` as 2nd column of the `Courses` combobox, with column width=0 so it's invisible.

Then simply

```
=Courses.Column(1)
```

(`.Column` is 0-based)

Comment: Thanks a lot, works nicely (stupid me, I have even used the DLookup recently, but didn't think of it now!). Also your second option is quite convenient